# Java Swing - button image Drag&Drop - showing image while moving

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I have some drag and drop functionality working - I can drag a button to another button and the image from button1 drops in button2 and it's working. What I need to accomplish is to see the image moving with the mouse, not to see the plus sign, which is the default behaviour.

Do you know how to change that behaviour? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean the cursor?

Comment: I mean to have the image moving, maybe the cursor, I don t know how to explain that, is for a card game for my student project, think like moving a card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you're simply trying to change the cursor image. You can change the image when the drag event starts and replace it to default the default when done.

Defaullt cursor image:

```
myPanel.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
```

Custom cursor image:

```
Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Image cursorImg = toolkit.getImage("myCursorImg.gif");
Cursor myCursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(cursorImg, new Point(myPanel.getX(), 
           myPanel.getY()), "img");
myPanel.setCursor(myCursor);
```

---

**Update:** You've cleared things up for me now, you wish to have a ghost image trailing your cursor.

You'll have to add a GlassPane on which you project the image as you're dragging. Be warned though as this has the possibility to slow your application down.

A great tutorial on how to achieve this is given [here](http://www.jroller.com/gfx/entry/drag_with_style_in_swing).